# What's the best way to search from several map<key,value>?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have created a `vector` which contains several `map<>`.

```
vector<map<key,value>*> v;
v.push_back(&map1);
// ...
v.push_back(&map2);
// ...
v.push_back(&map3);
```

At any point of time, if a `value` has to be retrieved, I iterate through the `vector` and find the `key` in every `map` element (i.e. `v[0]`, `v[1]` etc.) until it's found. Is this the best way ? I am open for any suggestion. This is just an idea I have given, I am yet to implement this way (please show if any mistake).

**Edit**: It's not important, in which `map` the element is found. In multiple modules different `map`s are prepared. And they are added one by one as the code progresses. Whenever any `key` is searched, the result should be searched in all `map`s combined **till that time**.

Comment: why do you want map objects in a vector ? Order is important?

Comment: No Order is not important. At certain stage, I get a new `map` which, I want to add (as search should happen in all the existing `map`s)

Comment: In that case wouldn't it be more efficient to keep one map and update this map by copying values from the new map. So when you do look up you just have to look up on this single map so you have `O(log n)` performance?

Comment: Why can't you put all the objects into a single map? And why do you store pointers to maps, instead of the maps themselves?

Comment: @Naveen, the problem is that all `map`s are created independently. Will extending the first `map` with upcoming `map` objects be efficient ?

Comment: If creating a copy of the `key` and `value` of your map is not a costly operation, I would go with the single map approach.

Comment: Why do you have multiple maps? Is it important to know which map the element belongs to? Can you create one map to hold all of the elements? Do you have code that does lookups in just one map?  ... Please clarify

Comment: I can't see how this can be reasonably answered. We don't know what you're trying to do, under which constraints the solution has to work, or what would make one solution "better" than another.

Answer (score 3):

Without more information on the purpose and use, it might be a little difficult to answer.  For example, is it necessary to have multiple map objects?  If not, then you could store all of the items in a single map and eliminate the vector altogether.  This would be more efficient to do the lookups.  If there are duplicate entries in the maps, then the key for each value could include the differentiating information that currently defines into which map the values are put.

Comment: all maps are created independently. Will extending the first map with upcoming map objects be efficient ?

Comment: Well ... maybe, maybe not.  It depends on the number of lookups that are performed.  The original creation of each map would cost (I think) O(n log n).  Then to add those items to an existing map, it is basically going to be another O(n log n) operation.  So given that limitation, your independent set of vectors are going to be more efficient up front.  But if enough searches for objects are performed after the final map has been created, then eventually the cost would be worth it.

Comment: You can also make a std::map return a list of equivalent elements instead of only one is that is what you end up needing.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to know which submap the key was found in, try:

```
unordered_set<key, pair<mapid, value>>
```

This has much better complexity for searching.

Answer (score 1):

If the keys do not overlap, i.e., are unique througout all maps, then I'd advice a `set` or `unordered_set` with a custom comparision functor, as this will help with the lookup. Or even extend the first map with the new maps, if profiling shows that is fast enough / faster.

If the keys are not unique, go with a `multiset` or `unordered_multiset`, again with a custom comparision functor.

You could also sort your `vector` manually and search it with a `binary_search`. In any case, I advice using a tree to store all maps.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how your maps are "independently created", but if it's an option, I'd make just one global map (or multimap) object and pass that to all your creators. If you have lots of small maps all over the place, you can just call `insert` on the global one to merge your maps into it.

That way you have only a single object in which to perform lookup, which is reasonably efficient (O(log n) for multimap, expected O(1) for unordered_multimap).

This also saves you from having to pass raw pointers to containers around and having to clean up!